# Retrieving raster data is taking forever

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to create a grid that has classification and band values from raster data.
I have 3 tables in the Postgre:

1. A grid with a specific size, let's say 1.28 x 1.28 km (I have created using the fishnet);
2. Raster data that intersects with the grid 1. But the dimensions of the raster are 109.8 x 109.8 km
3. OSM data that intersects with grid 1 and raster 2 data.

My idea is to iterate the grid table over the raster data and extract band values and osm data (classifications). Currently, I have written this query to intersect the grid and raster data

```
"""WITH vector_data AS (
  SELECT ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,1) band1, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,2) band2,
         ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,3) band3, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,4) band4,
         ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,5) band5, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,6) band6,
         ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,7) band7
  FROM raster_grid g, public.t32ulc_entire_tile rast 
  WHERE ST_Intersects(rast.rast, g.geom)
 )

select  (band1).geom as geom, 
        (band1).val as b1, 
        (band2).val as b2,
        (band3).val as b3,
        (band4).val as b4,
        (band5).val as b5,
        (band6).val as b6,
        (band7).val as b7

from vector_data;"""
```

the query works perfectly in the Dbeaver SQL editor (very fast, about 1 sec). So next step should be iteration over the raster area. In this step, I want to use Python, but this script

```
def connection_db():
    """
    Establish connection to the DB
    :param db_name: Database name

    :return: cursor, engine

    """

    # connect to database
    conn = psycopg2.connect( host='127.0.0.1', port="5432")
    # conn.autocommit = True
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://manap:t&aN:/2zk,QM;>8h@127.0.0.1:5432/db_geo_data')

    
    return cursor , engine

test = """
WITH vector_data AS (
  SELECT ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,1) band1, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,2) band2,
         ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,3) band3, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,4) band4,
         ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,5) band5, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,6) band6,
         ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,7) band7
  FROM raster_grid g, public.t32ulc_entire_tile rast 
  WHERE ST_Intersects(rast.rast, g.geom)
 )

select  (band1).geom as geom, 
        (band1).val as b1, 
        (band2).val as b2,
        (band3).val as b3,
        (band4).val as b4,
        (band5).val as b5,
        (band6).val as b6,
        (band7).val as b7

from vector_data;
"""
print('here')
cursor.execute(test)
    # Fetch result
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print((rows))
```

Unfortunately, this executing forever. What is wrong here? I tried with small raster data too, that is also is not working. How can I handle this? My idea is iterate the grid over the raster area and feed that data into ML training. Is that possible within the postgresql without python? Any suggestions?

Comment: How many records does your query result in? `WITH vector_data AS (
  SELECT ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,1) band1, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,2) band2,
         ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,3) band3, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,4) band4,
         ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,5) band5, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,6) band6,
         ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,7) band7
  FROM raster_grid g, public.t32ulc_entire_tile rast 
  WHERE ST_Intersects(rast.rast, g.geom)
 )

select count(*) from vector_data;`

Comment: There might be a possilbility of that your database IDE shows only limited amount of data because you are not using `order`.